# 0365 - Update Choices in Site Column

Tags: office-365, site-column

Using Site Columns, created several different Columns to use across portal.  There were changes on a "Choice" field in one of those columns and although I get the message: "You're about to update all lists using this site column with the settings on this page."

Nothing changed on the current list at all.  I went back to the Settings and checked the Column where the choices were to change and nothing was updated.

1. Is there something I need to push to update the Site Column in the list (on the Site Column area it is updated)
2. Is it a time issue?  Does Microsoft do this once a week or is it immediate?
3. Do I have to add the "updated" Site Column to the list and update the data manually?

I can't seem to find any information.  Thanks.

Comment: are you making changes on the site column on the content type hub? if yes you might need to go individual site collection setting and tick 'Refresh all published content types on next update' under Content Type publishing

Comment: I am really struggling with changes made in one libary not rolling across the libraryies when a SITE column...is this a bug or as designed? If as designed, how is it SITE?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, It will not update automatically it is called as bug factor.
Consider the scenario that, there are number of list using site column and number of data using that choice in that if you want to replace some choices, in future some previous end users get lagged. 
  If we need it means we have to change manually.
If anything I said wrong in above please excuse !..